# Possible to create a custom viewport camera/light/empty representation?

Tags: python, 3d-view

First of all, I’m missing the right word here, hence my vague title. What is the name of this:
[image]

Please don’t say it’s a camera :D. I mean how do you call the 3D viewport representation of the camera or light or empty? Is it also a gizmo?

My actual question is: Is it possible to create custom 3D representations with the same properties (selectable but not editable) through the Python API?

Comment: I think this isn't possible. The drawing of cameras, bones, etc. is in Blender's C code and can't be customized via Python. You can see this in https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/draw/modes/object_mode.c and search for 'camera' and 'buffer_camera_instance'.

Comment: There are several types of empties to choose from in the Add menu. As to i.a. cameras and lights, why should it be possible?

Comment: @Lukasz-40sth I don't want to change the camera or lights, I used it merely as an example. I would like to create a custom representation for an add-on of mine. With the add-on, you can create projectors and I would like to have a unique 3D-representation for the projectors.